# I want reference of this sloka

Tags: mahabharata, reference-request, harivamsa

I want reference for this slokaa

"Mudrayasah Gacchantu Rajno ye
Gantumipsavah Na chamudra praveshtavyo Dwarapalasya Pasyatah"
This sloka belong Harivamsa Prava of Mahabharata

I want chapter and sloka number of this sloka .

Comment: This is from Harivamsa Purana Bhavishya Parva, Chapter 74. Mudraya saha gacchantu rajno ye gantumipsavah- second half of verse 24. Na camudrah praveshtavyo dvarapalasya pashyatah- first of verse 25

Comment: It is form harivamsa purana

Comment: That’s exactly what I’ve given you shloka and chapter reference from Harivamsa purana.

Comment: In harivasma purana Bhavishya parva did not have 74 chapter

Comment: Where are you checking?

Comment: In wisomlib.com

Comment: Okay I don’t think wisdomlib has Harivamsa. Anyway you got an answer showing 74th adhyaya. If all your answers are satisfactory you can accept by clicking on the tick button, below voting arrows.

Comment: Can you tell meaning

Comment: Meaning is given in your answer below in Hindi. English translation is: those who want to go out (leave the city), they must take with them the royal mudra. Those who don’t have the mudra, they must not be able to enter while the doorkeeper is watching.

Comment: I added the meaning by editing the answer only. You can check that.

Comment: One small request  in that explain of seal is there

Comment: No explanation of seal not there. Only mention of seal there. They don’t explain what the seal is

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Verse is from [Sri Harivanśha Puran 3.74.24-25](https://archive.org/details/harivamshapurana/page/n1005/mode/2up) (Bhavishya Khanda, 74th Adhyay, Shloka 24-25):

[image]

[Gita Press - Gorakhpur version, with Tikka of Sri Ramnarayan Dutt Shastri]

> एक एव महाद्वारो गमनागमने सदा। मुद्रया सह गच्छन्तु राज्ञो ये
> गन्तुमीप्स्वः॥२४॥
> न चामुद्रः प्रवेष्टव्यो द्वारपालस्य पश्यतः। यावदागमनं मह्यं तावदेवं भविष्यति॥२५॥
>
> eka eva mahādvāro gamanāgamane sadā | mudrayā saha gacchantu rājño ye
> gantumīpsvaḥ || na cāmudraḥ praveṣṭavyo dvārapālasya paśyataḥ | yāvadāgamanam mahyaṃ tāvadevaṃ bhaviṣyati ||
>
> There will always be only one big door for entry and exit. Those who wish to go (leave the city) must take the royal seal with them. Those without a seal must not be able to enter when the doorkeeper is watching. Till my return, it must happen in this way.

Comment: Thanks you very mach

Comment: Very nice answer 